# Redirect directive ignored in .htaccess when using URL parameters

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, redirect

I have a default .htaccess file that comes with drupal. In order to redirect externally linked pages from the old website to the new one I usually use statements like

```
Redirect /foo http://www.example.com/bar
```

This works as expected.

But the statement is totally ignored when looking like

```
Redirect /index.php?x=y http://www.example.com
```

and the request runs through the mod_rewrite rules from Drupal at the end of the .htaccess file.

Do you know what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

`Redirect` does not match URL parameters, it will only match the **PATH** of a url.

## Solution

You **CAN** match the `QueryString` variable with `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule`. Here is a working (but untested) snippet that you can try:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} x=y
RewriteRule ^index.php http://www.example.com [R=301]
```

You should note a few things about this:

1. The `RewriteCond` line is really a [regex (regular expression)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), so you will have to escape any special characters you add to it (such as punctuation), and the first `?` is omitted, but any further URL parameters with have to include the `&` (`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} x=y&a=b`).
2. This method is equvilent to a `Redirect`, because I specified the HTTP status code (a [HTTP 301 Redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301), which is permanent).

#### Credits

- [How can I match query string variables with mod_rewrite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252238/how-can-i-match-query-string-variables-with-mod-rewrite) - Stack Overflow